# How to skip precompilation of unused vendor assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In Rails 3.1 "rake assets:precompile" precompiles all separate .css and .js that are in vendor/assets/.. folders. For example, it creates separate precompiled files for jquery, jqueryui libraries and all other files from "vendor" folder.

My web site only references application.css and application.js. Why does it precompile every single vendor asset as a separate file? I am not using those files directly. Is there a way to remove those vendor files from precompilation list?

My concern is that it takes extra time and disk space to precompile those files that I will never use in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a [bug in 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2876).

The regex that is used to capture assets to precompile was a little to broad and was including files that it wasn't supposed to.

This is fixed in in 3-1-stable, but is after the 3.1.1 RC1 tag so will probably be in 3.1.2.